# I want to install Cvode on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am about to install the software “Cvode” which operates under LINUX, Ubuntu, and since I am a total novice in this field, I guess I need some directions which would tell me where I should start from and take me forward gradually to the final steps of installation. Is there anyone who could give me a hand on this? It would very appreciated. Thanks for your attention.
You can find this software here: [Cvode](http://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/download/download.php). Thanks.

Comment: I would have to register myself to try this. :\ – Download the archive, extract the archive, read the README, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you downloaded, `cvode-2.8.2.tar.gz` is a GZip-compressed `tar` archive. It contains the package you wish to install. Here is how you can get started:

1. Create a directory for unpacking the archive. I'm using `cvode_install`, you could use something else.

   mkdir $HOME/cvode_install
    cd $HOME/cvode_install
2. Inspect the archive. replace `/path/to/tarfile` with the actual path on your system. Pipe the output to `less` to display it a page at a time (hit <kbd>Space</kbd> for the next page)

   tar tzvf /path/to/tarfile/cvode-2.8.2.tar.gz | less -Mers
3. If the archive is OK, extract the archive into the current directoru (`$HOME/cvode_install`):

   tar xzvf tzvf /path/to/tarfile/cvode-2.8.2.tar.gz
4. Look for, and read, files with names in upper case, e.g. `README`, `INSTALL`, they will help you find the next step.
5. If all there is is a large `.run` or `.sh` file, you can read it with `less`, or, if you trust the provider, run it with:

   chmod +x thefile
   ./thefile

Comment: @http://askubuntu.com/users/471375/pourya-danaeifar: Then please click the Checkmark to Accept my answer.